# How to create every possible 4 digit code, out of 6 numbers and without using duplicates?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a list that contains every possible 4-digit code, using numbers from 1 to 6. I can't use duplicates, so `[1, 2, 3, 3]` is not allowed.

I came up with the idea to first create all 1296 possible codes WITH using duplicates and then filtering out every code that doesn't fit the rule: no duplicates. In order to do this I would need to first create these 1296 codes. So starting with `[1, 1, 1, 1]` and ending with `[6, 6, 6, 6]`.

Can somebody help me out? I know it should do `[1, 1, 1, 1]` and then `[1, 1, 1, 2]` etcetera, but I don't know how to implement this.

I forgot to mention: I started of by trying to create one single code that followed the rules. This didn't go so well either. This was my code:

```
single_code([]).
single_code(Code1):-
  length(Code1, Y),
  Y < 4,
  random_between(1, 6, X),
  \+member(X, Code1),
  single_code([X|Code1]).
single_code(Code1):-
  single_code(Code1).
```

It eventually went into a loop and I don't know how to stop it from doing that. There is something I don't understand about recursion and I don't know what.

Comment: Don't you think hardcoding 1296 is quite complex compared to the description. What will you do if you want to generate a 10-digit codes? Store all 60M possibilities?

Comment: Perhaps instead of creating a list of all such 4-digit codes, perhaps first look for a way to generate a *single* 4-digit code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I editted my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using predicates and builtins

A possible idea is to user `member/2`. Although `member/2` can perform member-checks, it does more: it can enumerate over alle elements of a list (e.g. `member(X,[1,4,2,5])`), or construct all possible lists where a certain value is a member (e.g. `member(2,L)`).

Here we can use it to enumerate over the possibilities. So `member(A,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).` will unify `X` with 1, 2, ..., 6.

We can use this to exhaustively enumerate all possible lists with four elements like:

```
four([A,B,C,D]) :-
    member(A,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(B,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(C,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(D,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
```

which will by backtracing produce all lists with four elements. Such that the eBlements are all members of the lists `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Now of course we will also produce things like `[2,2,3,3]` where there are duplicates. We can however easily add `A \= B` as a constraint to check whether `A` is not equal to `B`. So by adding six constraints, we can prevent any duplicate elements:

```
four([A,B,C,D]) :-
    member(A,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(B,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(C,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(D,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    A \= B,
    A \= C,
    A \= D,
    B \= C,
    B \= D,
    C \= D.
```

Now this is however still inefficient: we here perform a *generate-and-test* approach where we first generate a full sample, and then check if it is valid. But if for instance `A` and `B` are equal, then regardless of the values we pick for `C` and `D`, we can already backtrack. So usually it is better to *interleave* generating and testing, like:

```
four([A,B,C,D]) :-
    member(A,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    member(B,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    A \= B,
    member(C,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    A \= C,
    B \= C,
    member(D,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),
    A \= D,
    B \= D,
    C \= D.
```

Now it works more efficient, but it is still inelegant: a lot of code is repeated. It makes it very hard to for instance generate lists with six elements without any duplicates. We can solve this by generalizing the approach.

The first thing we need is a way to generate members of a virtual list `[1..n]`. We can do this with:

```
between(A,B,A) :-
    A =< B.
between(A,B,C) :-
    A < B,
    A1 is A+1,
    between(A1,B,C).
```

If we call `between(1,6,X).` it will unify `X` with all the elements `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, and `6`.

So now we can declare a more generic variant:

```
distinct_n(A,B,N,L) :-
    distinct_n(A,B,N,[],L).

distinct_n(_,_,0,_,[]).
distinct_n(A,B,N,Xs,[X|R]) :-
    N > 0,
    between(A,B,X),
    \+ member(X,Xs),
    N1 is N-1,
    distinct_n(A,B,N1,[X|Xs],R).
```

So now we can generate a list `L` with `N` numbers from `A` to `B` (both inclusive), with `distinct_n(A,B,N,L).`.

If we now thus generate all 3-lists with distinct elements ranging from 1-4, we obtain:

```
?- distinct_n(1,4,3,L).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 4] ;
L = [1, 3, 2] ;
L = [1, 3, 4] ;
L = [1, 4, 2] ;
L = [1, 4, 3] ;
L = [2, 1, 3] ;
L = [2, 1, 4] ;
L = [2, 3, 1] ;
L = [2, 3, 4] ;
L = [2, 4, 1] ;
L = [2, 4, 3] ;
L = [3, 1, 2] ;
L = [3, 1, 4] ;
L = [3, 2, 1] ;
L = [3, 2, 4] ;
L = [3, 4, 1] ;
L = [3, 4, 2] ;
L = [4, 1, 2] ;
L = [4, 1, 3] ;
L = [4, 2, 1] ;
L = [4, 2, 3] ;
L = [4, 3, 1] ;
L = [4, 3, 2] ;
false.
```

If we now want to generate a list of these lists, we can use `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(L,distinct_n(1,4,3,L),LL).
LL = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2]].
```

## Using CLP(FD)

Prolog also has a **C**onstraint **L**ogic **P**rogramming library over **F**inite **D**omains (`clpfd`). This allows to specify code in a short way, like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

distinct_n(A,B,N,L) :-
    length(L,N),
    L ins A..B,
    all_distinct(L),
    label(L).
```

Se we first import the library, then we construct a list `L` of length `N`. All the elements of `L` are in `A..B`, and the elements are `all_distinct/1`. Finally by using `label/1` we start a procedure to find solutions to the constraint logic programming problem.

Comment: I have still one question remaining: Why was my previous code for getting 1 random code going into a loop and what would be the solution to that.

Comment: @Boomer your last clause is a perfect infinite loop: `single_code(Code1):- single_code(Code1).`